# How to write a code for update logged in user data into firebase using flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm a newbie for flutter and currently learning it by developing a  small system for my university project. Below are my user register and profile view which I referenced from YouTube. But I do not know how to write a code for edit and delete the logged in user data (the personal information such as name and address)...

```
class RegMuser extends StatefulWidget {
const RegMuser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_RegMuserState createState() => _RegMuserState();
}

class _RegMuserState extends State<RegMuser> {
bool hidePassword = true;
final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final nameEC = new TextEditingController();
final emailEC = new TextEditingController();
final nricEC = new TextEditingController();
final passwordEC = new TextEditingController();
final confirmPasswordEC = new TextEditingController();

final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final nameField = TextFormField(
   autofocus: false,
   controller: nameEC,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
   validator: (value) {
     RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^.{3,}$');
     if (value!.isEmpty) {
       return ("Name Cannot Be Empty");
     }
     if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
       return ("Enter A Valid Name");
     }
     return null;
   },
   onSaved: (value) {
     nameEC.text = value!;
   },
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
     labelText: 'Name',
     border: OutlineInputBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
     ),
   ),
 );

 final emailField = TextFormField(
   autofocus: false,
   controller: emailEC,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
   validator: (value) {
     if (value!.isEmpty) {
       return ("Please Enter Your Email");
     }
     if (!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-z]").hasMatch(value)) {
       return ("Please Enter Valid Email");
     }
     return null;
   },
   onSaved: (value) {
     nameEC.text = value!;
   },
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
     labelText: "Email",
     border: OutlineInputBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
     ),
   ),
 );

 final nricField = TextFormField(
   autofocus: false,
   controller: nricEC,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
   validator: (value) {
     RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'[0-9]');
     if (value!.isEmpty) {
       return ("NRIC Cannot Be Empty");
     }
     if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
       return ("Enter A Valid NRIC");
     }
     if (nricEC.text.length != 12) {
       return ("Enter A Valid NRIC");
     }
     return null;
   },
   onSaved: (value) {
     nricEC.text = value!;
   },
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.card_membership),
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
     labelText: "NRIC",
     border: OutlineInputBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
     ),
   ),
 );

 final passwordField = TextFormField(
   autofocus: false,
   controller: passwordEC,
   obscureText: hidePassword,
   validator: (value) {
     RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^.{6,}$');
     if (value!.isEmpty) {
       return ("Password Is Required For Login");
     }
     if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
       return ("Please Enter Valid Password");
     }
   },
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
     labelText: "Pasword",
     border: OutlineInputBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
     ),
     suffixIcon: InkWell(
       onTap: togglePasswordView,
       child: Icon(
         Icons.visibility,
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );

 final confirmPasswordField = TextFormField(
   autofocus: false,
   controller: confirmPasswordEC,
   obscureText: hidePassword,
   validator: (value) {
     if (confirmPasswordEC.text != passwordEC.text) {
       return "Password Don't Match";
     }
     return null;
   },
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
     labelText: "Confirm Pasword",
     border: OutlineInputBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
     ),
     suffixIcon: InkWell(
       onTap: togglePasswordView,
       child: Icon(
         Icons.visibility,
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );

 final signUpButton = Material(
   elevation: 5,
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
   color: Colors.blue[400],
   child: MaterialButton(
     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
     minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     onPressed: () {
       signUp(emailEC.text, passwordEC.text);
     },
     child: Text(
       "Sign Up",
       style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 20,
         color: Colors.white,
         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );

 return Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
   appBar: AppBar(
     backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
     elevation: 0,
     leading: IconButton(
       icon: Icon(
         Icons.arrow_back,
         color: Colors.black,
       ),
       onPressed: () {
         Navigator.of(context).pop();
       },
     ),
   ),
   body: Center(
     child: SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Container(
         color: Colors.white,
         child: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
           child: Form(
             key: formkey,
             child: Column(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               children: <Widget>[
                 SizedBox(height: 20),
                 nameField,
                 SizedBox(height: 20),
                 emailField,
                 SizedBox(height: 20),
                 nricField,
                 SizedBox(height: 20),
                 passwordField,
                 SizedBox(height: 20),
                 confirmPasswordField,
                 SizedBox(height: 20),
                 signUpButton,
                 SizedBox(height: 10),
               ],
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
}

void togglePasswordView() {
 setState(() {
   hidePassword = !hidePassword;
 });
}

void signUp(String email, String password) async {
 if (formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
   await _auth
       .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
       .then((value) => {postDetailsToFirestore()})
       .catchError((e) {
     Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e!.message);
   });
 }
}

postDetailsToFirestore() async {
 FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 User? mUser = _auth.currentUser;
 Muser muser = Muser();

 muser.email = mUser!.email;
 muser.uid = mUser.uid;
 muser.name = nameEC.text;
 muser.nric = nricEC.text;

 await firebaseFirestore
     .collection("mUsers")
     .doc(muser.uid)
     .set(muser.toMap());
 Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Account Created Successfully");

 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil((context),
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => homePage()), (route) => false);
}
}
```

```
Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      "Name",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${loggedInUser.name}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      "Email",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${loggedInUser.email}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      "Position",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${loggedInUser.post}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      "Department",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${loggedInUser.dept}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      "Hospital",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${loggedInUser.hosp}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      "Address",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${loggedInUser.street} ${loggedInUser.city} ${loggedInUser.postcode} ${loggedInUser.state} ${loggedInUser.country}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Import the Firebase package
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

// Create an instance of the Firebase authentication
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

// Create a function to update logged in user data
Future<void> updateUserData(String name, String email, String phone) async {
  // Get the current logged in user
  FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
  // Create a user update profile
  UserUpdateInfo userInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
  // Update the user profile with the provided data
  userInfo.displayName = name;
  userInfo.email = email;
  userInfo.phoneNumber = phone;
  // Finally update the user profile
  await user.updateProfile(userInfo);
}
```